# How to call hooks at the top level if they're depending on processed data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The [first rule](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) of React Hooks states to “only call hooks at the top level”.

But how do we then handle cases like below when the hook `useState` needs data that has to be processed before calling the hook?

Or does "top level" mean everything above the function's `return`, hence the code below is alright?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router'
import { parse } from 'query-string'

function MyComponent() {
  const { search } = useLocation()
  const { sorting } = parse(search)
  const [currentFilter, setCurrentFilter] = useState(sorting)
  return (
    // content
  )
}
```

Comment: Is there a problem with how the code is now, i.e. are your location hook or parse function async? You could update the state with ```useEffect``` hooks, depending on the order you need to receive/process the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule refers to never calling hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Has to do with the fact that hooks relies on the declared order to update the values.

Your code isn't wrong and doesn't break the first rule, cause no matter what everytime you call `MyComponent` `useLocation` will always be the first one to get called and `currentFilter` the second.

The following would break the first rule

```
const Component = () =>{
    const [foo] = useState()
    if(condition) const [bar] = useState(null)
}
```